# Escape special characters in Room Database Query

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have the following code in my Dao file.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ${Test.TABLE_NAME} WHERE primary_key = :primaryKey LIMIT 1")
fun selectTest(primaryKey: String): Test?
```

The problem is `primaryKey` is a String that can have a `/` in it. Such as `Test/4`. This causes the query to fail. I tried putting quotes around the `:primaryKey` but then Room doesn't bind it anymore. I also tried adding in escaped quotes into the `primaryKey` String that would get bound to the query, but that doesn't work either.

Thoughts on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

The table name, as it includes special characters, needs to be enclosed in characters acceptable to both SQLite and ROOM.

In SQLITE you could use one of the following :-

```
`tablename` 
"tablename" 
'tablename' 
[tablename]
```

However ROOM is fussier in that it won't let you use the middle two. As such try :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM `${Test.TABLE_NAME}` WHERE primary_key = :primaryKey LIMIT 1")
fun selectTest(primaryKey: String): Test?
```

or

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM [${Test.TABLE_NAME}] WHERE primary_key = :primaryKey LIMIT 1")
fun selectTest(primaryKey: String): Test?
```

## Testing

- Note the above is in-principle code and has not been tested or run, so it may contain minor errors. However, the equivalent java code has been tested by adapting code from an answer to another question for convenience.

using :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM `/cards` WHERE card_name LIKE :cardName")
Cards[] getCardsByName(String cardName);

@Query("SELECT * FROM [" + GamesDatabase.TABLENAMECARDS +"] WHERE card_name LIKE :cardName")
Cards[] getFunnyCardsByName(String cardName);
```

- `GamesDatabase.TABLENAMECARDS` is the same table name but as a CONSTANT i.e. /cards

The above Dao's were used using :-

```
    String cardToGet = "%/";
    Cards[] retrievedCards = mGamesDao.getCardsByName(cardToGet);
    for (Cards c: retrievedCards) {
        logCardsInfo(c,"GETCARDSBYNAME");
    }

    retrievedCards = mGamesDao.getFunnyCardsByName(cardToGet);
    for (Cards c: retrievedCards) {
        logCardsInfo(c,"GETCARDSBYFUNNYNAME");
    }
```

The logCardsInfo method writes the Card, it's name, it's value, it's id, it's Folder and it's Category to the log the TAG being the 2nd parameter passed.

Where Cards contains a pack of cards (with an extra suit called ooops, not that suits equate to Category, Folders there are two per Category but 7's are in the normalcards Folder) but the name of the card with a value of 7 is 7/ instead of 7, so 5 cards will be extracted by both as per :-

```
2019-09-16 15:01:46.084 19140-19140/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/GETCARDSBYNAME: Card Name is 7/
        Value is 7
        CardID is 10
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category Spades
2019-09-16 15:01:46.089 19140-19140/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/GETCARDSBYNAME: Card Name is 7/
        Value is 7
        CardID is 23
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category Hearts
2019-09-16 15:01:46.094 19140-19140/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/GETCARDSBYNAME: Card Name is 7/
        Value is 7
        CardID is 36
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category Clubs
2019-09-16 15:01:46.101 19140-19140/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/GETCARDSBYNAME: Card Name is 7/
        Value is 7
        CardID is 49
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category Diamonds
2019-09-16 15:01:46.107 19140-19140/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/GETCARDSBYNAME: Card Name is 7/
        Value is 7
        CardID is 62
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category ooops
2019-09-16 15:01:46.110 19140-19140/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/GETCARDSBYFUNNYNAME: Card Name is 7/
        Value is 7
        CardID is 10
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category Spades
2019-09-16 15:01:46.114 19140-19140/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/GETCARDSBYFUNNYNAME: Card Name is 7/
        Value is 7
        CardID is 23
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category Hearts
2019-09-16 15:01:46.118 19140-19140/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/GETCARDSBYFUNNYNAME: Card Name is 7/
        Value is 7
        CardID is 36
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category Clubs
2019-09-16 15:01:46.121 19140-19140/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/GETCARDSBYFUNNYNAME: Card Name is 7/
        Value is 7
        CardID is 49
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category Diamonds
2019-09-16 15:01:46.122 19140-19140/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/GETCARDSBYFUNNYNAME: Card Name is 7/
        Value is 7
        CardID is 62
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category ooops
```